# Trying to update an SQL table from within Power BI

Tags: sql-update, powerbi

I am attempting to update an SQL table from within Power BI.  I have many automated reports around the company where I work, and my goal is for them to report back when they are viewed so I know if one isn't updating properly.  I am able to do this with my custom applications, but not yet for power bi.

I wrote a simple script and was able to run it in the query editor and it returned no errors and successfully updated the table in question:

```
update [ReportStatus] set
    [ViewedUTC] = GetUTCDate()
output inserted.[ViewedUTC] [Output] 
where [Name] = 'ServerMonitor'
```

[image: Script]

When I click "Close & Apply" I receive the error message that I cannot use a nested update statement (though this is not nested) in a select statement (this is not a select statement) where it is not the immediate source of rows for the insert statement (this is not an insert statement and it is the immediate source of rows.

[image: Error Message]

I've googled this extensively and while others have the same error message, I was unable to find one that was attempting to update and did so successfully.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!
Lexen

Answer (score 2):

PBI is a business analytics tools as such it does not allow you to add values to your database, you can only extract and analyze your information in different ways, it's a Business Inteligence progam as such not for inputs but for data analytics.

Comment: I understand that is their business answer, but the fact that the code can run successfully in the editor and that the error message implies updates, inserts, merges and deletes are possible under the right circumstances, lends some hope.

Answer (score 2):

It is a nested update, because Power BI will compose query like this:

```
select * from (update [ReportStatus] set [ViewedUTC] = GetUTCDate() ...) SourceQuery
```

It does that, because it needs to add joins and conditions at runtime. Obviously the above query is not valid.

To get information about report usage, look at report's metrics (go to the workspace and click the dots icon next to the report or dashboard):

[image]

For more information read [Monitor usage metrics for Power BI dashboards and reports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-usage-metrics) article. Also take a look at [Track user activities in Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-admin-auditing).

Generally speaking, updating database contents like this is not a good idea. In the best case, reporting is a read only operation (e.g. you could offload it to a secondary read-only replica). Also it will not work for imported and live connections.

Comment: Thank you.  This added a lot of context for what is going on under the hood.

Answer (score 2):

See [here](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2018/10/07/power-query-write-data/) for a response from Microsoft people.

> #### Can You Use Power Query In Power BI Or Excel To Write Data To A Data Source?
>
> The short answer: **no**.
>
> The long answer:
>
> It is, technically, possible to use Power Query (in either Power BI or Excel) to write data to a data source; for example, here’s an [old post](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2013/12/09/updating-data-in-sql-server-with-power-query/) I wrote showing how to run a UPDATE statement to update data in a table in SQL Server. However because the Power Query engine may evaluate a value or statement more than once when a query is executed, it is therefore not safe or supported to use it to try to create, insert, update, delete or otherwise change data in a data source – it should only be used to read data. You may see some functions listed in the M function reference that suggest otherwise but they aren’t supported either, and indeed may not work at all.

Comment: I saw that.  I was unable to utilize the technics they laid out in it, but it was nice to know someone else was trying to work through the same issue.

Comment: It is a pretty old post so it's possible they've changed how things work for unsupported and discouraged practices.